# При подключении скриптов к wordpress появляется ошибка. granim.min.js?ver=4.8:2 Uncaught Error: `#canvas-basic` could not be found in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

При подключении скриптов к wordpress в консоле поясвляется ошибка - granim.min.js?ver=4.8:2 Uncaught Error: `#canvas-basic` could not be found in the DOM. В HTML есть блок . в Чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В месте подключения скрипта?

Comment: @Qwertiy
Прикрепил скриншот.

Comment: @Qwertiy да "подключение" в WordPress это просто вывод в html `<script type='text/javascript' src=...`. Ошибка у него при работе скрипта.

Comment: @KAGGDesign прикрепил скриншот.

Comment: да вижу, а в чем дело - непонятно. Точно есть такой элемент в DOM в момент jQuery(document).ready ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign прикрепил еще один скриншот.

Comment: а что это за файл вдруг index.html? Какое отношение он имеет к WP?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Боже мой, я забыл перенести блок в header.php, простите за тупость, только начинаю учить WP, сажу на него свой первый проект. Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @KAGGDesign напишите что-то чтобы я вам мог + поставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл index.html на скриншоте содержит элемент #canvas-basic, но сам файл отношения к WordPress не имеет. Потому запущенный скрипт и не находит в DOM этого элемента.